# Saving Django User in Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm currently working on my first Django app, which allows registered users to submit content through a basic form.

It works thus far with one caveat: when the form is displayed, the user ("Author") is presented with a drop-down list of all users instead of automatically populating that field with the user's name. This is obviously not acceptable.

This goal is to have the registered user's name automatically populate the form. I've seen some various potential solutions to similar problems, but nothing that addresses anything this specific.

I attempted setting the Author field in the model to "unique=True," but that resulted in a database error when migrating it.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated:

Model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    copy = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)   
    def __unicode__(self):
         return " %s" % (self.title)
```

Form:

```
class StoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Story
```

View:

```
@login_required
 def submit_story(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    story_form = StoryForm()
    return render_to_response("report/report.html",
                             {'form': story_form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
elif request.method =="POST":
    story_form = StoryForm(request.POST) 
    if story_form.is_valid():
        new_story = Story()
        new_story.title = story_form.cleaned_data["title"]
        new_story.topic = story_form.cleaned_data["topic"]
        new_story.copy = story_form.cleaned_data["copy"]
        new_story.author = request.user
        new_story.zip_code = story_form.cleaned_data["zip_code"]
        new_story.latitude = story_form.cleaned_data["latitude"]
        new_story.longitude = story_form.cleaned_data["longitude"]
        new_story.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/report/all/")
    else:
        story_form = StoryForm()
        return render_to_response("report/report.html",
                                {'form': story_form},
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(Request))
```

EDIT: I think I found the relatively simple answer: I just removed the 'author" field from the form and kept the view the same. I was able to post under the registered user's name this way. I think this works, unless something I'm unaware of (which is plenty) is incorrect or bad protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do something similar:

Base class for all models who are associated with a user:

```
class UserOwnedModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Base class for all forms who are associated with a user:

```
class UserOwnedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    exclude = ["user", ]

    def __init__(self, user, data=None, *arguments, **keywords):
        if data:
            data['user'] = user.id
            forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, data=data, *arguments, **keywords)
```

I'm not sure if it's the best solution (and will be glad for any input or suggestions) but it works for me.
This of course completely removes the user field from the form, so if you need to display the user name, you'll have to play with the code.

---

## EDIT

Also, instead of this:

```
new_story = Story()
new_story.title = story_form.cleaned_data["title"]
new_story.topic = story_form.cleaned_data["topic"]
new_story.copy = story_form.cleaned_data["copy"]
new_story.author = request.user
new_story.zip_code = story_form.cleaned_data["zip_code"]
new_story.latitude = story_form.cleaned_data["latitude"]
new_story.longitude = story_form.cleaned_data["longitude"]
new_story.save()
```

You can do this:

```
new_story = story_form.save()
```

---

## EDIT 2

Something like this:

```
class Story(UserOwnedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    copy = models.TextField()
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)   
    def __unicode__(self):
         return " %s" % (self.title)

class StoryForm(UserOwnedForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story

@login_required
def submit_story(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        story_form = StoryForm(user=request.user)
    ....
    elif request.method =="POST":
        story_form = StoryForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if story_form.is_valid():
            new_story = story_form.save()
            .....
        else:
            story_form = StoryForm(user=request.user)
            ....
```

I also changed my initial code a bit.

Comment: Interesting solution. Did you have the same issue with a drop-down menu exposing all users? And this ended it? Also, is your edit with saving the form necessary or just more proper for working with forms created directly from models?

Comment: You get the drop down selection menu since it's the default widget for the *ForeignKey* field, and yes I had that too. I did not want to put the user name in the forms since it's clear to the user what's his name, and so my code removes it from the form (for display). No, it's not necessary but it's more object oriented to do it in the form object itself.

Comment: Excellent. And using your method, it automatically populated the user field with the registered user's name? If so, that would be close to perfect.

Comment: Well, almost, all you need to do is to construct the form with the additional user parameter, like: *StoryForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)* or *StoryForm(user=request.user)*.

Comment: Oh, forgot something for clarity. Your base use User model is a new and separate model, correct? Same for the form model? And the StoryForm in my example would use: StoryForm(UserOwnedModel): , or something to that effect?

Comment: I edited my answer with how it should look like with your code.

Comment: That's in addition to the UserOwned Model, correct? I know it seems obvious.

Comment: Huh. It won't print out the form_as.p in the template now. "'StoryForm' object has no attribute '_errors'"

Comment: Oh. I changed my initial code a bit in my last edit.  I forgot to add a line at first, which calls to the super *__init__* inside the *UserOwnedForm*.  Please copy it again and it should work.